# SWT layout which can be minimize and maximize

Tags: java, layout, swt

I am from ZK background and new to eclipse plugin development. I have 5 labels with corresponding text-boxes and one button. I want them in a group, which can be minimize and maximize. In ZK, we have a UI widget exactly for this purpose, [GroupBox](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/layout/group_box). To see its functionality, visit [ZK fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/17h1sue/1-Groupbox-bug-nbsp-added-at-Client-because-of-indentation)

I am sure there must be a widget available in SWT for this functionality, just I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that matches your description is a Shell, which you can define as minimizable or maximizable.

```
Shell shell = new Shell(parentShell, SWT.MAX | SWT.MIN);
Group group = new Group(shell , SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN);
group.setText("Group");
group.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

Label label = new Label(group, SWT.NONE);
label.setText("Label one:");

Text text = new Text(group, SWT.BORDER);

...

shell.open();
```